# Get text value from a form on an Excel sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get text to populate mail from text forms.

The code won't recognize my forms. They are named correctly and have the same name in the code.

The "form control" textbox is greyed out.
I tried ActiveX text box, not greyed out, but does not work.
I tried a normal format textbox in Excel, but does not work.

I get

> runtime error 424 object required

on `SubjectText = SubjectTextBox.Value`.

```vb
Sub Create_Emails()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim RecipientsRange As Range
    Dim RecipientCell As Range
    Dim BodyText As String
    Dim SubjectText As String
    Dim GreetingOne As String
    Dim GreetingTwo As String
    Dim AdditionalText As String
    
    ' Set the range for email addresses (B4:B24)
    Set RecipientsRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B24")   
    
    ' Get user input from text boxes
    SubjectText = SubjectTextBox.Value
    GreetingOne = GreetingOneTextBox.Value
    GreetingTwo = GreetingTwoTextBox.Value
    BodyText = BodyTextBox.Value
    
    ' Get additional text from cells C4 to C24
    AdditionalText = Join(Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C24").Value), " ")
    
    ' Create an instance of Outlook
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Loop through each recipient email address and send an email
    For Each RecipientCell In RecipientsRange
        If RecipientCell.Value <> "" Then ' Check if the cell is not empty
            ' Create a new email
            Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            ' Set email properties
            With OutlookMail
                .To = RecipientCell.Value
                .Subject = SubjectText
                .Body = GreetingOne & " " & RecipientCell.Value & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & AdditionalText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & GreetingTwo & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & BodyText
                .Display ' Use .Send instead of .Display to send emails automatically
            End With
            
            ' Release the email object
            Set OutlookMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next RecipientCell
    
    ' Release the Outlook application object
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that the code is part of a module and not of the form itself?

Comment: The error is saying that `SubjectTextBox` is not set to be a valid object (or TextBox in your case). Is `SubjectTextBox` embedded in a Worksheet and, if so, is it a Form or ActiveX just now? What exactly is its name (ie in the Worksheet)?

Comment: The code is in a module.
The name of the textbox is "SubjectTextBox" should i then write SubjectTextBox.SubjectTextBox.Value?
The textbox is embedded on Sheet1 its an active x textbox.

Comment: Am i supposed to answer in the comments here?

Comment: If it's helping explain the question further then you can edit your original question - the edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of your question.  Best not to update the code in your question with corrected code as that would make it look like a pointless question when people are looking for answers to similar problems in the future.  The Answers section should just be used for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refer them with the parent sheet object. Something like this

```
SubjectText = Worksheets("Sheet?").SubjectTextBox.Value
```

where `Sheet?` is the name of the sheet on the tab at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I thought i had commented this, but apparently not.
But thank you for your help!